# Modeling API objects with respect to internal implementation

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns, service

If you create a REST service that serves `Banana` objects, there are likely two different conceptual models of those bananas.

1. What is used on the REST API you serve to the public
2. What is used internally to the application, with possible DB fields that aren't exposed externally

One might reflect this reality in code by having two classes, with conversions between them:

```
class Banana {
  private String color;
}

class InternalBanana {
  private int id;
  private String color;
  private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

  public toBanana() {
    return new Banana(color);
  }
}
```

Pros:

- Marshalling to Json via `jackson` is simple
- `Banana` can be used while test-driving the API code

Cons:

- Code duplication
- Converters of *internal* objects need to be updated any time the API is updated

So what if we merge the two classes:

```
class Banana {
  private int id;
  private String color;
  private ZonedDateTime createdAt;

  public String toApiJson() { ... }
}
```

Pros:

- No duplication
- Seems more robust to changes in the public API

Cons:

- No model of REST API objects
- Marshaling to Json requires special code
- Internal fields will often be `null`

Which approach is likely to be the most efficient over the lifetime of a given service?